# Microsoft TFS and Visual Studio 2008 - project hierarchy changing on server

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

We are using TFS 2013.  I am trying to share a VS 2008 website project using Microsoft TFS.  Both PCs have the Team Foundation Server MSSCCI Provider Plugin installed.

We created a new Team Project in VS 2013 (Shell), and mapped it to the local project file/folder directory, which builds successfully on PC1.

Note: For some reason the sln file was not under source control initially.  On PC1, the Project/Solution file structure is: ProjectName > ProjectName.sln  (in our example the solution file is NOT one level above the other project files).

On PC2, we are able to map and “get” the project files from the TFS server without a problem.  However, when the project is opened from the local solution file, a new folder is created within the project (using the project name), causing the website to not load in VS 2008. The solution file is looking for the project in the newly created folder.

The solution file and project hierarchy coming from the TFS server do not appear to be correct.  Why is this different than on PC1?  Is there a way to modify the source directory the solution file should be looking for the project?

We haven't had any issues setting up VS 2012 projects. There is limited information on VS 2008.  Has anyone encountered this issue before?  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the source explorer in visual studio (post 2010) and look at the layout as was checked into the server you should find the problem. A get will get what is checked in so it sounds like the other maybe is doing something hinkie..

Note: Post VS 2010 you can open the same solution in multiple VS versions with no side effects. This is not the case with pre-2010.